# issue in getting different results each range of while iterations

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a mysql table called 'products'. 
I'm trying to get all the table records in my site, divided by page.

Every page consists in a simple CSS class. p1, p2, p3, p4, etc.

I do a simple while loop.

```
      while (...)) { ?>

         <p class="p1"><?php echo $row['product'] // etc ?> </p>

      <?php }
```

This works great, but all records have "p1" class.

**My goal is to get 3 products for each page, example:**

```
<p class="p1">1</p>
<p class="p1">2</p>
<p class="p1">3</p>

<p class="p2">4</p>
<p class="p2">5</p>
<p class="p2">6</p>

<p class="p3">7</p>
<p class="p3">8</p>
<p class="p3">9</p>

etc
```

i tried this code which works with only a problem that I will explain later

```
$i = 0;
$class = 1;

while (...) {

   $i++;
   if ($i % 3 ) {

        $class++;

   } ?>

  <p class="p<?php echo $class ?>">1</p>

<?php }
```

This code works, but unfortunately I always get p1 with 2 records and p2,p3,p4,p5 ecc with 3 records.

**RESULTS**

```
<p class="p1">1</p>
<p class="p1">2</p>

<p class="p2">3</p>
<p class="p2">4</p>
<p class="p2">5</p>

<p class="p3">6</p>
<p class="p3">7</p>
<p class="p3">8</p>
```

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you never change $i, so ...

Comment: put `$i++` after `if` or like `if($i++ % 3)`

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post adding $i++;

Comment: Shift the `$i++` below the `if` block and switch your `if` condition to something like `if($i && $i % 3 === 0)`.

Comment: @JonStirling it works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a small mistake. `$class` is 1 when `$i` is 1 and 2. When `$i` is 3, the `$class` variable increments and becomes 2. Try changing the if condition to include case for `$i` to be 0 so that you can get first three objects to have class as 1.
For example,

```
$i=0;
if($i != 0 && i%3==0) {
        $class++;
    }
```